# How to open a GUI program using a remote connection (ssh)?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, ssh, remote-access

I am using Ubuntu/gnome (10.04) to remotely connect to two (slightly different) embedded systems running Ubuntu (12.04). I use the following command for connection:

```
ssh -X -l username 192.168.1.blah
```

Then, in the terminal I can use a command that run a GUI based program, say `gedit`:

```
gedit filename.txt
```

Now, on the first system, a nice `gedit` window is opened on my PC desktop, allowing me to edit the remote file. However, on the second system, I get the following error message:

`** (gedit:3637): WARNING **: Could not connect to session bus`

Why is it so, and how can I make the 2nd connection to work like the 1st one?

**UPDATE 1:** The 1st machine reports `linaro 12.03`, not `12.04`

**UPDATE 2:** Here's the output for `dbus` search (`dpkg -l *dbus* | grep ^i`) on the 1st machine:

```
ii  dbus                                   1.4.14-1ubuntu1                                            simple interprocess messaging system (daemon and utilities)
ii  dbus-x11                               1.4.14-1ubuntu1                                            simple interprocess messaging system (X11 deps)
ii  gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4               0.5.0-0ubuntu4~linaro2                                     typelib file for libdbusmenu-glib4
ii  gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4                0.5.0-0ubuntu4~linaro2                                     typelib file for libdbusmenu-gtk4
ii  libdbus-1-3                            1.4.14-1ubuntu1.3                                          simple interprocess messaging system (library)
ii  libdbus-1-dev                          1.4.14-1ubuntu1.3                                          simple interprocess messaging system (development headers)
ii  libdbus-glib-1-2                       0.94-4                                                     simple interprocess messaging system (GLib-based shared library)
ii  libdbus-glib1.0-cil                    0.5.0-3build1                                              CLI implementation of D-Bus (GLib mainloop integration)
ii  libdbus1.0-cil                         0.7.0-4                                                    CLI implementation of D-Bus
ii  libdbusmenu-glib4                      0.5.0-0ubuntu4~linaro2                                     library for passing menus over DBus
ii  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4                     0.5.0-0ubuntu4~linaro2                                     library for passing menus over DBus - GTK+ version
ii  libdbusmenu-gtk4                       0.5.0-0ubuntu4~linaro2                                     library for passing menus over DBus - GTK+ version
ii  libdbusmenu-qt2                        0.9.0-0ubuntu2                                             a Qt library that implements the DBusMenu spec
ii  libdconf-dbus-1-0                      0.10.0-0ubuntu1                                            simple configuration storage system - D-Bus library
ii  libnih-dbus1                           1.0.3-4ubuntu2                                             NIH D-Bus Bindings Library
ii  libqt4-dbus                            4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1linaro1                                  Qt 4 D-Bus module
ii  python-dbus                            0.84.0-2                                                   simple interprocess messaging system (Python interface)
ii  qdbus                                  4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1linaro1                                  Qt 4 Dbus Tool
```

And here it is for the 2nd machine:

```
ii  dbus                                   1.4.18-1ubuntu1                            simple interprocess messaging system (daemon and utilities)
ii  dbus-x11                               1.4.18-1ubuntu1                            simple interprocess messaging system (X11 deps)
ii  gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4               0.6.1-0ubuntu3                             typelib file for libdbusmenu-glib4
ii  gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4                0.6.1-0ubuntu3                             typelib file for libdbusmenu-gtk4
ii  gir1.2-gjsdbus-1.0                     1.32.0-1ubuntu1                            GObject introspection data for GJS
ii  gstreamer-dbus-media-service           0.1.17-upstream-0ubuntu3                   Media service for Ubuntu Mobile
ii  libdbus-1-3                            1.4.18-1ubuntu1                            simple interprocess messaging system (library)
ii  libdbus-glib-1-2                       0.98-1ubuntu1                              simple interprocess messaging system (GLib-based shared library)
ii  libdbusmenu-glib4                      0.6.1-0ubuntu3                             library for passing menus over DBus
ii  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4                     0.6.1-0ubuntu3                             library for passing menus over DBus - GTK+ version
ii  libdbusmenu-gtk4                       0.6.1-0ubuntu3                             library for passing menus over DBus - GTK+ version
ii  libdbusmenu-qt2                        0.9.2-0ubuntu1                             Qt implementation of the DBusMenu protocol
ii  libnih-dbus1                           1.0.3-4ubuntu9                             NIH D-Bus Bindings Library
ii  libqt4-dbus                            4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4                           Qt 4 D-Bus module
ii  python-dbus                            1.0.0-1ubuntu1                             simple interprocess messaging system (Python interface)
ii  python-dbus-dev                        1.0.0-1ubuntu1                             main loop integration development files for python-dbus
ii  qdbus                                  4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4                           Qt 4 D-Bus tool
```

Comment: My best educated *guess* says you haven't installed `dbus` on the remote end (2nd machine). Could you include the output of `dpkg -l *dbus* | grep ^i` in your question of *both* machines?

Answer (score -3):

you may want to check your openssh settings stored at /etc/ssh/ssh_config.  make sure the line with X11Forwarding is set to "yes".

Comment: The `-X` flag enables forwarding separate from the ssh_config file.  And if they are able to use that flag and get it to work as they said they can, then `X11Forwarding` is permitted on the SSHd on the remote system.  So this doesn't provide the asker with an answer at all.

Comment: The error would be totally different if this was the cause.